# Python, aggregate list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

with no knowledge of Python, but some other reasonable experience in SW programming I stumbled into the following problem…. Out of a big data set containing unstructured information I (thanks to Stackoverflow) could already come to the following dataset (list of dictionaries, simplified/reduced for this question on Stackoverflow)

```
data  = [ {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B1', 'RES': 'true'}, 

          {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B2', 'RES': 'true'},
          {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B2', 'RES': 'false'},
          {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B2', 'RES': 'inconclusive'},          

          {'KEY_A': 'A2', 'KEY_B': 'B3', 'RES': 'true'},
          {'KEY_A': 'A2', 'KEY_B': 'B3', 'RES': 'false'}, 

          {'KEY_A': 'A3', 'KEY_B': 'B4', 'RES': 'false'}
         ]
```

which looks very reasonable for upcoming processing steps.

From a logical perspective KEY_A together with KEY_B build a “logical key” (in fact each line is a certain measurement, where KEY_A and KEY_B are some criteria, other criteria was deleted from the list, because it is not needed anymore) which have 1 to n (here n=3) results assigned (true, fals, inconclusive).

Now the job is to “aggregate” that data such, that for identical “logical keys”, ‘RES’ should be reduced to one value only, e.g. lines 2,3,4 (which all contain 'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B2') , three different ‘RES’ values should aggregate to
{'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B2', 'RES': 'false'}
based on the “rule”: “Worst one wins”, where ‘false’ is worse than ‘inconclusive’ is worse than ‘true’
So finally the aggregated data should look like:

```
data  = [ {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B1', 'RES': 'true'},
          {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B2', 'RES': 'false'},          
          {'KEY_A': 'A2', 'KEY_B': 'B3', 'RES': 'false'},
          {'KEY_A': 'A3', 'KEY_B': 'B4', 'RES': 'false'}
         ]
```

In this resulting list, there is one unique  set of of KEY_A KEY_B, and the “worst result” out of “true, inconclusive, false” won.

A potential solution “strategy” I can somehow imagine looks like:
Get unique KEY_A list (will be A1, A2, A3)
Loop over data based on that unique KEY_A list
for each entry
get unique KEY_B list (For A1 it will be B1, B2. For A2 it will be B3. For A3 it will be B4
Loop over data based on that unique KEY_B list
apply “worst one wins rule”

However
a)  this does not look too elegant

b)  I assume, Python or libraries like e.g. pandas have functions to aggregate such data based on rules (hat a look at the Pandas manual Release 1.0.3, but could not find such a function) . I found aggregation stuff in Stackoverflow, but in those examples, the aggregation was always a sum up or other maths of values (no logic like “worst one wins” or other) of different entries (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099683/python-dictionary-of-list-of-list-aggregate)) .

c)  I anyhow have to research how to implement this

Any advice how to proceed (or even code) is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned `pandas`, here is one way of doing that. The key is that `'false' < 'inconclusive' < 'true'` when doing string comparison, so you can actually do a `groupby` and `min`.

```
import pandas as pd

data  = [ {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B1', 'RES': 'true'}, 
          {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B2', 'RES': 'true'},
          {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B2', 'RES': 'false'},
          {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B2', 'RES': 'inconclusive'},          
          {'KEY_A': 'A2', 'KEY_B': 'B3', 'RES': 'true'},
          {'KEY_A': 'A2', 'KEY_B': 'B3', 'RES': 'false'}, 
          {'KEY_A': 'A3', 'KEY_B': 'B4', 'RES': 'false'} ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df.groupby(['KEY_A', 'KEY_B']).min().reset_index().to_dict(orient='records'))

[{'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B1', 'RES': 'true'}, 
 {'KEY_A': 'A1', 'KEY_B': 'B2', 'RES': 'false'}, 
 {'KEY_A': 'A2', 'KEY_B': 'B3', 'RES': 'false'}, 
 {'KEY_A': 'A3', 'KEY_B': 'B4', 'RES': 'false'}]
```

If you'd rather have custom sorting, then you'll need to convert the `RES` column to categorical first. You can specify the desired order when doing so. For example:

```
category_order = ['inconclusive', 'false',  'true']
categories = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories=category_order, ordered=True)

df['RES'] = df['RES'].astype(categories)

print(df.groupby(['KEY_A', 'KEY_B']).min().reset_index())

#prints
  KEY_A KEY_B           RES
0    A1    B1          true
1    A1    B2  inconclusive
2    A2    B3         false
3    A3    B4         false
```

Have a look at the options of [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) if you'd like a different output format.

If you don't want to use pandas you could do someting similar with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: Hello ScootCork. Thank you so much!! An amazing solution. It worked right away.

Comment: You're welcome Uwe. If you are happy with the answer you can mark it as the accepted answer for your question.

Comment: Hello ScootCork, one more thing. It is coincidence, that the current verdicts are such, that they match the "min()" function. In case they will be different different (what I assume to happen soon), I would need some function, which evaluates those verdicts by "logic" (worst one wins or maybe even "best one wins"). I am wondering how to attach "myLogic()" to this. Any idea?

Comment: It is coincidence that this works for your given set of data. I've adjusted the answer with an option for custom ordering.